# ExtJs 4.1.2 ComboBox Update or Reload Based on another ComboBox

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, extjs, combobox

I'd like to know a way of how to update the list values of a ExtJs ComboBox. For instance, I have two comboboxs.
One Combobox determine what values the another ComboBox should have. So, after selecting some of those,
I click the drowndown list (combobox) to see the values. But i dont get reflected.

```
change: function (combofirst, record) {
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        -- -- --
        -- -- --
        success: function (response) {
                var combosecond = Ext.getCmp('defaultPackageType');
                //I am unable to update the combosecond from below snippet.
                combosecond.store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                    fields: ['value', 'display'],
                    data: [
                            ["N", "No"],
                            ["A", "All accounts"]
                        ] //json response
                });
            },
            failure: function (record, action) {}
    });
});
```

In short, how can I change the values of a ComboBox already has with ajax only.

Hope someone can help me

Thanks

Comment: With wich ExtJs version and framework? Modern or classic?

Comment: You must update the store data (or reconfigure the combo) with new data. As a best solution you need to set some params on the proxy of the second combo box store and reload the store. Re-assigning the store of combobox is not the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would also agree to the comment, that creating every time a new store and bind it to the combobox is not the optimal solution. I don't know really the reason why this should be done, but nevertheless here is a working example by using bindStore:

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3ci0

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.field.ComboBox', {
    // ...
    listeners: {
        change: {
            fn: function (cb) {

                Ext.Ajax.request({
                    url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums',
                    method: 'GET',
                    timeout: 60000,

                    success: function (response) {
                        var jsonResp = response.responseText;
                        let jsonObj = Ext.JSON.decode(jsonResp, true)

                        var combo2 = Ext.getCmp('myCombo2');
                        combo2.bindStore(Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                            fields: ['id', 'title'],
                            data: jsonObj
                        }));
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
});
```

For selection of value 1 the data is loaded from a different url.
But I would think about whether a new proxy call is necessary and whether you can achieve your requirements by using filters or something else.